# Experiencing Windows Hello PIN/Fingerprint "This option is currently unavailable"

Tags: windows, windows-hello, intune

I am having the same problem as this post:  [Windows Hello PIN/Fingerprint "This option is currently unavailable"](https://superuser.com/questions/1464842/windows-hello-pin-fingerprint-this-option-is-currently-unavailable)

I changed the same three polices in the solution to be "Not Configured"

> under Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
> Components\Windows Hello for Business\ must be in the state "Not
> configured".

I had mine set to Enabled. I changed to Not Configured. I have "Turn on convenience PIN sign-in" enabled - I checked my registry and it is showing on.

Still getting unavailable. Is there anything that must be done to "fix" or overwrite the settings that were made when these were set to enable.

If not, I am wondering if I have an InTune policy that is impacting it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlNWc.png)

Comment: "Some settings ..." is only displayed for two reasons.  The first is that a policy prevents the user from modifying it, so that is likely the case, with the machine being managed by InTune, the other reason is that some other required option is disabled and/or being managed by a group policy and is explicitly disabled.

Comment: Makes sense @Ramhound - I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: I know very little about InTune, what can you tell us, about the configuration of the machine with regards to it? I just know it's a cloud based implementation. I believe could be described as a cloud based AD solution. Looks like InTune integrates with Azure AD.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I finally found the solution for my case.

The problem is that I have connected the laptop to a school/university/work account. The work account has sign-in policy restrictions. This work account does not have to be your sign-in account at all.

You can find it under settings -> accounts -> access work or school. If there is one, just disconnect and you can find windows hello back.

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Comment: worked for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. On CMD Type “Regedit” and hit enter to open Registry Editor.
2. Go to the following registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System
3. Look for a DWORD value named AllowDomainPINLogon. If it’s not there, right-click System and select New>DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name it AllowDomainPINLogon, and set its value to 00000001.
4. Now go to Start menu and click Settings >Click Sign-in options> Check the Option is available now.

Comment: Thank you -- I have that reg key.  I am pretty sure that is what the GPO for "Turn on convenience PIN sign-in" adds.  But that key is there for me.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help.